# HTML form, 2 submit style buttons for 2 different PHP actions/files

Tags: php, html, sql, post

I have an HTML file upload form that accepts a file and submits it to a database through PHP, which works fine. The code:

```
<form method="post" action="confirm.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label>Upload File</label>
 <input type="file" name="file">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Preview" formtarget="_blank">
</form>
```

My issue is that i need to combine the preview php and the submission php. Both work independently using the $file but I'm trying to make it so the user uploads -> hits the preview button -> previews the info -> hits submit -> info goes into database, but the upload php will say the file is invalid.
I used some PHP code to display the contents in an html table to verify the information before submitting it to the database, like so:

```
<body>
<div class="phpTableWrap">
<?php

$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pw = "root";
$db = "uwsTest";

$connect = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pw, $db);

if ($connect->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else{
    echo'success!';
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);

$file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$maxPreviewRows = PHP_INT_MAX;  // this will be ~2 billion on 32-bit system, or ~9 quintillion on 64-bit system
$hasHeaderRow = true;

    echo '<table>';
    if ($hasHeaderRow) {
        $headerRow = fgetcsv($handle);
        echo '<thead><tr>';
        foreach($headerRow as $value) {
            echo "<th>$value</th>";
        }
        echo '</tr></thead>';
    }
    echo '<tbody>';
    $rowCount = 0;
    while ($row = fgetcsv($handle)) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($row as $value) {
            echo "<td>$value</td>";
        }
        echo '</tr>';

        if (++$rowCount > $maxPreviewRows) {
            break;
        }
    }
    echo '</tbody></table>';
   }
?>
</div>
```

Is there a way to share the uploaded file with both PHP files so that I can insert data from the preview page?

Comment: You should POST the upload to both php files with AJAX rather than rely on the html form action.

Comment: But how would I do that to show the preview table with confirm.php and then allow the user to hit a final submit button for upload.php?

Comment: So you send to preview first then with the callback of the preview you display the data and show the submit button and then the next post goes to submit.

Comment: Is there a way only through PHP/HTML? I'm having trouble getting the AJAX to work within the wordpress site. I was hoping there was a way to make one button an actual submit type and one just a button with an 'onclick' action

Comment: There is not a way with only PHP/HTML, some javascript will be required but maybe not AJAX.  If you show a preview by parsing the form fields with javascript and displaying with javascript then only actually submit to the php file with the submit button you can avoid using AJAX.

Comment: Ok, I will look into that. Also, sorry to ask again, but what If I combined both actions into one PHP file? This way the form would only post to one php file and I could control 2 actions in the file?

Comment: Yes you could do that too, you would still need javascript to add a hidden form field like <input type='hidden' name='action' value='preview' /> when you click the preview button and them have it submit the form after that... so you know in the php file which  type of action you are sending

Comment: Perfect, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your preview button add a hidden field like `<input type='hidden' name='action' value='preview' />` with javascript before submitting and detect that in your PHP file:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'preview') {
 // do preview stuff
}
```

Comment: Quick question: I have the if($_POST....) code around my php for the preview function, and then the submit post around my submit PHP code. I also added the hidden input type in my form. Would this be the correct javascript for this instance?

var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
x.setAttribute("type", "hidden");

Comment: That does create the element but you need to also add the name and value attributes and append it to the form.  Add id="myForm" to your form then var form = document.getElementById("myForm"); form.appendChild(x);